# Terraform workspace naming convention

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

I have 4 terraform directories for 4 branches of a repo (dev, qa, uat, prod). I was able to interpolate every variable I needed by adding "branch" as an env variable in TF cloud, and using it across my resources. However, the workspace name itself is the problem. Trying to add an interpolated variable to it throws an error - workspace name can't have those. And since my branches auto PR to each other (code is instantly promoted from dev all the way up to prod) it causes conflicts - because all tf files now have different hardcoded workspace names. Yes, I could just ignore the terraform file when I promote my branches, but the idea is that editing dev.tf affects all others. Any way to go around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move away from having multiple branches.
Branches track changes on the same codebase. Also,the workspaces are usable when you have a single backend configuration but multiple instances of your infra. An example can be, multiple developers are using a single AWS account to create their own sandbox application using the same IaC.

As you have multiple environments (dev, qa, uat, prod) I will suggest to use the same codebase and different configuration files.
Something like:

- common.tfvars
- dev.tfvars
- qa.tfvars
- uat.tfvars
- prod.tfvars

when you want to change something edit only the `dev.tfvars`, test your changes and then add those config chnages to the rest files.
Also, consider tagging your prod infra and apply changes only using git tags there.

Comment: I actually managed to solve it by adding a backend.hcl file for each branch remote, and keeping them out of repos, that way they don't get committed, while main.tf stays the same.